# Вывод пользователей в модальное окно

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Сделал модальное окно, пользователи в него выводятся, но проблема в том, что они выводятся в ряд, как можно сделать чтобы новый пользователь, новая строка(\n не работает, просто ставит пробел).
Может в css как то добавить, или только в js можно?

```js
const addUserToModalWindow = () => {
  const contentWindow = document.querySelector(".usersList");
  socket.on('users', (users) => {
    users.forEach((item) => {
      contentWindow.innerHTML += `${item}` + '\n';
    });
  });
}
```

Вот как выводится
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возьми  каждого пользователя сунь в отдельный тег, и стилизуй  как душе угодно

Comment: Подскажите как это сделать? добавить span перед ${item}?

Comment: Можете просто сделать `<div>${item}</div>` или `${item}</br>`

Answer (score 1):

Сделал вам пример тегов, в которые можно обернуть юзеров и увидеть как они будут выводиться.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="usersList">
  User<br>
  User<br>
  User<br>
  User<br>
  User<br>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="usersList">
  <span>User</span>
  <span>User</span>
  <span>User</span>
  <span>User</span>
  <span>User</span>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="usersList">
  <div>User</div>
  <div>User</div>
  <div>User</div>
  <div>User</div>
  <div>User</div>
</div>

<hr>

<ul class="usersList">
  <li>User</li>
  <li>User</li>
  <li>User</li>
  <li>User</li>
  <li>User</li>
</ul>
```